# How do I iterate through data in a panda data frame?

Tags: python-3.x

I have created a 5 day moving average for 5 years worth of data. How do I iterate through this to show if the moving average is rising or falling for every single day. My code is simply giving me 1 integer answer rather than a rising (+1) or falling(-1) answer for every day. Thank you!

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file:///C:/Users/James Brodie/Desktop/USDJPY.csv', header=1, index_col=0)
ma5 = df['PX_LAST'].rolling(window=5).mean()
ma8 = df['PX_LAST'].rolling(window=8).mean()
ma21 = df['PX_LAST'].rolling(window=21).mean()


ma5x = []
for i in ma5:
    if i > i-1: 
        ma5x = 1
    elif i < i-1: 
        ma5x = -1
    else:
        ma5x = 0

print(ma5x)
```

Thank you!

Comment: show the structure of your data.

Comment: It's unclear what you expect, but it is no surprise you are getting a singe integer as your `ma5x`, since your loop always assigns an integer to `ma5x`!

Comment: I'm trying to get an output for every day for 5 years. Either +1 or -1 if the moving average is rising or falling. But i'm only getting 1 output instead of output for every day for the 5 years. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ma5 = [5,2,2,3,3,2,5]
ma5x = []
lastItem = ma5[0]
for currItem in ma5[1:]:
    if currItem > lastItem: 
        ma5x.append(1)
    elif currItem < lastItem: 
        ma5x.append(-1)
    else:
        ma5x.append(0)
    lastItem = currItem
print(ma5x)
```

gives:

```
[-1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 1]
```

The elements of a list are best represented in pandas as a Series object (put own index of choice for rows replacing `list(range(len(ma5x)))` with anything you need):

```
print('-----------')
import pandas as pd 
pd_ma5x = pd.Series(ma5x, index=list(range(len(ma5x))))
print(pd_ma5x)
```

gives:

```
-----------
0   -1
1    0
2    1
3    0
4   -1
5    1
dtype: int64
```

> **Using own index be aware that `pd_ma5x` size is one less than that of `ma5`**

Comment: Claudio, thank you, you're a legend!! You've saved me hours of frustration.

Comment: Yes please delete and thank you for again for the help.